# To Find Orthogonal Trajectories Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is that "A family of curves consists of ellipses with a common axis of length 2. Find an equation of the orthogonal trajectories for this family."

There is no given equation for a family. How do I find the orthogonal trajectories equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my take on this is that the ellipses might as well be defined by
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
With $a=1$ so whether it ends up being the semi-major or semi-minor axis, the axis parallel to the $x$-axis will be of length $2$. The free parameter of the family will be $b$, so we solve for $b$,
$$\frac{y^2}{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}=b^2$$
Differentiate
$$\frac{2yy^{\prime}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)-y^2\left(-\frac{2x}{a^2}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)^2}=0$$
Multiply by $\frac{a^2}{2y}$ and set the numerator to zero and the differential equation for the family of ellipses if $y^{\prime}(a^2-x^2)+xy=0$. For the orthogonal trajectories, replace $y^{\prime}$ by $-1/y^{\prime}$ and simplify to get $xyy^{\prime}=a^2-x^2$. Separate variables and solve:
$$y\,dy=\frac{a^2-x^2}xdx$$
$$\frac12y^2=a^2\ln|x|-\frac12x^2+\frac12C$$
$$x^2+y^2=a^2\ln(x^2)+C$$
Plot a few curves and their orthogonal trajectories and call it a wrap.
[image: ortho.png]

Comment: Thank you so much! this is very helpful! :-) I'm gonna figure out through your answer.